# How to optimise multiple on click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created multiple functions to happen on click, it works fine but I was just wondering if this is the best way to do it or if there is a better / more stream lined approach.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smorris1900/eL0zwkgr/8/)

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/*windows*/ 
$('.window1').on({'click': function(){$('#windows').attr('src','images/windowcolours/windows-anthracite-grey.png') .attr('style','display:block;');}});
$('.window2').on({'click': function(){$('#windows').attr('src','images/windowcolours/window-jet-black.png') .attr('style','display:block;');}});
$('.window3').on({'click': function(){$('#windows').attr('src','images/windowcolours/windows-slate-grey.png') .attr('style','display:block;');}});
$('.window4').on({'click': function(){$('#windows').attr('src','images/windowcolours/windows-cream.png') .attr('style','display:block;');}});
$('.window5').on({'click': function(){$('#windows').attr('src','images/windowcolours/windows-silver-grey.png') .attr('style','display:block;');}});
```

Comment: Optimise how? Write less code?

Comment: You're supposed to include a [mcve] in the question itself and not only a link to an external resource. And asking for refactoring is off-topic (or with working code and example more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: just not in the subject but you can use ```$(document).ready(function () {``` rather than ```jQuery(document).ready(function($){```

Comment: It's usable, but you can make all windows have the same class. Inside them have an invisible form with the value of the image. Then create one function to rule them all.

Comment: You might like to try: https://codereview.stackexchange.com for working code

Comment: @axelaxel FYI the current recommendation is to just use `$(handler)` - you would use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` if `$` might be defined elsewhere, so `$(document).ready(function() ` is actually worse that what OP is using.  https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @axelaxel The use of `jQuery` with an aliased argument is useful in some cases, notably Wordpress. Although if you want to shorten the document.ready definition then you can use `jQuery(function($) {...`.

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona I see what you did there...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan learning smth thanks

Comment: Please use class for DOM events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your fiddle link doesn't work, however I can see from the context of the JS logic that you can DRY this up.

Firstly use a common class on all the elements, then use a `data` attribute to store custom metadata on each one. Then you can assign a single click event handler to all those elements, something like this:

```html
<div class="window" data-src="images/windowcolours/windows-anthracite-grey.png">Foo</div>
<div class="window" data-src="images/windowcolours/window-jet-black.png">Foo</div>
<div class="window" data-src="images/windowcolours/windows-slate-grey.png">Foo</div>
<div class="window" data-src="images/windowcolours/windows-cream.png">Foo</div>
<div class="window" data-src="images/windowcolours/windows-anthracite-grey.png">Foo</div>
```

```js
var $windows = $('#windows');

$('.window').on('click', function() {
  $windows.prop('src', $(this).data('src')).show();
});
```

Also note the use of `show()` over explicitly setting `display: block` using `css()`.

Comment: this solution is good because you can easily see what image is supposed to display and modify it +1